# java.io.EOFException when using spark-submit with yarn as master on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, httpserver, eofexception

I'm trying to run a jar file with this spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 3g --class my.package.Main my-jar-file.jar
```

The class Main is the jar's main class, and here's the contents (all in Scala):

```
object Main{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        val server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("master", 8000), 0)
        val backend = new MainProcess()
        val handlerRoot = new RootHandler()
        handlerRoot.initProcess(backend)

        server.createContext("/", handlerRoot)
        server.setExecutor(null)

        server.start()
        println("Server is started at " + server.getAddress().getHostString() + ":" + server.getAddress().getPort())
    }
}
```

The class MainProcess is the class where I do the stuff with Spark and Spark GraphX library using the files obtained from HDFS. This is how I configure the SparkContext in MainProcess class:

```
class MainProcess{
    val config = new SparkConf()
    config.setAppName("Final GraphX App - Main")
    val sc = new SparkContext(config)
   ...
}
```

The app seems to be running okay and the final status returned a success, but the app simply closes instead of running continuously as it's supposed to be a running server. I can only open the link master:8000 once and it's back to unable to connect when I tried refreshing the page. Here's the log from running the app:

```
18/04/06 15:45:59 ERROR yarn.YarnAllocator: Failed to launch executor 2 on container container_1522920902032_0027_01_000003
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception while starting container container_1522920902032_0027_01_000003 on host slave2
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorRunnable.startContainer(ExecutorRunnable.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorRunnable.run(ExecutorRunnable.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator$$anonfun$runAllocatedContainers$1$$anon$1.run(YarnAllocator.scala:523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "master/10.100.69.207"; destination host is: "slave2":57914; 
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.startContainers(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.NMClientImpl.startContainer(NMClientImpl.java:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorRunnable.startContainer(ExecutorRunnable.scala:122)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:687)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1900(Client.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:729)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:725)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:725)
    ... 21 more
```

This app is basically a web app made using Java HTTP Server (com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer) and it uses Spark to process big data. The requests sent are accepted by the handler class and a new thread is made to run the Spark job on background. The user can send another request to check if the Spark job is finished, so the finished result can be shown to the web page. The problem is, the server is "killed" every time Spark claims to have finished a job (but in this case, failed a job).
I'm using Spark 2.2.0 built for Hadoop 2.7 and Hadoop 2.7.1. All data files are in HDFS.

Comment: Is `server.start()` non-blocking?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele no, it's not stopping when I used spark-submit locally (using Windows OS). But it stopped when I submitted in cluster (using Linux Ubuntu)

Comment: Then you need to check YARN's logs, they'll mention when and why the application has been killed (possibly because of resources overuse?)

Comment: @ErnestKiwele already did, I already posted the error log. The main cause is the EOFException but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: [Please do not rollback the edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Your error indicates `slave2` machine is unable to be accessed... Please verify its running a node manager, and its ports are open for accepting YARN resource requests... Also, not clear at all why you're trying to run a web server within a Spark application